# Popups in a HTML file that stay in the screen

Tags: html, popup

I am trying to create popups in a custom HTML intended for reading. I spent a lot of time with Bootstrap Popover Plugin, and while they looked nice they frequently left the screen when you zoom in. I was told that the page doesn't have the info on your zoom level and cannot guarantee that popup will stay in the screen. (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp) when you zoom on the button) Instead of creating a hopeless solution, I need a nudge in the right direction.

Is there a known out of the box solution for popups in an HTML document that will stay in the screen, similar to a right-click popup box? It can be very basic.
Thanks in advance!